# Android Gradle plugin: pack NDK executable into APK

Tags: gradle, android-ndk

Trying to build NDK binary and pack it into APK.

**Studio Build:**

- Android Studio 3.2.1
- Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
- Version of Gradle Plugin: 3.2.1
- Version of Gradle:4.6
- Version of Java:JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- OS:macOS 10.13.6

**Steps to Reproduce:**

```
Android.mk
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../hello.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -g -fPIE
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -fPIE -pie
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

**Gradle config**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

sourceSets {          
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        jniLibs.includes = ['anything']
    }
}
```

If shared lib instead of executable was chosen, i can see `libhello.so` packed into apk under /lib. 
If it's set to **BUILD_EXECUTABLE**, nothing happens while the binary executable was compiled.  I don't know what i am missing in gradle config.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just FYI you don't need to explicitly provide the `-g` flag ever, and don't need to provide `-fPIE` or `-pie` unless you're using an old NDK and your `minSdkVersion` is less than 16 (if it is, you need to provide two executables since no executable works on both ICS and Lollipop).

Comment: @DanAlbert , thanks for your comments. i am not using old NDK so i clean all the flags. It looks much better now.